# Display Shapefile with leaflet and layer control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Hello 
I try to implement a leaflet pluging, for display a local hosted shapefile. The display of the shapefile work, but i want to add a layer control (for togle shapefile layer).
the plugin link : https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js

the demo link :http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#3/32.69/10.55

I want to implement the layer control on demo page

```
<script>
var m = L.map('map').setView([0, 0 ], 10);
var watercolor = 
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen 
Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 
3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a 
href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a 
href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>'
    }).addTo(m);

    var shpfile = new L.Shapefile('Fr_adm.zip', {
        onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
            if (feature.properties) {
                layer.bindPopup(Object.keys(feature.properties).map(function(k) {
                    return k + ": " + feature.properties[k];
                }).join("<br />"), {
                    maxHeight: 200
                });
            }
        }
    });
    shpfile.addTo(m);
    shpfile.once("data:loaded", function() {
        console.log("finished loaded shapefile");
    });
     // initialize stylable leaflet control widget
var control = L.control.UniForm(null, overlayMaps, {
        collapsed: false,
        position: 'topright'
    }
);
// add control widget to map and html dom.
control.addTo(m);


</script>
```

The shapefile Fr_adm.zip is displayed, but no layer control.
Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `overlayMaps` is not defined. Open your console and you should see an error stating this.

Looking at the documentation for L.control.UniForm maps ([an extension](https://github.com/chriscalip/L.UniformControl) of leaflet), we can see:

```
/ **
* standard leaflet code.
** /
// initialize stylable leaflet control widget
var control = L.control.UniForm(null, overlayMaps, {
        collapsed: false,
        position: 'topright'
    }
);
```

What is overlayMaps in this? To answer we need to take a look at the [documentation](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) for standard leaflet code. `overlayMaps` is a list of key, object pairs:

> ... we’ll create two objects. One will contain our base layers and
>   one will contain our overlays. These are just simple objects with
>   key/value pairs. The key sets the text for the layer in the control
>   (e.g. “Streets”), while the corresponding value is a reference to the
>   layer (e.g. streets).
>
> ```
> var baseMaps = {
>     "Grayscale": grayscale,
>     "Streets": streets
> };
>
> var overlayMaps = {
>     "Cities": cities
> };
> ```

Consequently, `overlayMaps` in your example should look like:

```
var overlayMaps = {"Name To Display":shpfile }
```

Once defined you should be able to create your layer control as normal.

Answer (score 0):

i see a mistake in the code, no overlayer value. So i try with this :

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">

//----------------
 var watercolor = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {

        });
     var geo = L.geoJson({features:[]},{onEachFeature:function popUp(f,l){
            var out = [];
            if (f.properties){
                for(var key in f.properties){
                out.push(key+": "+f.properties[key]);
        }
        l.bindPopup(out.join("<br />"));
    }
    }});
     var m = L.map('map', {
    center: [10, -1],
    zoom: 6,
   layers: [watercolor, geo ]
});

//}}).addTo(m);
      var base = 'Fr_admin.zip';
        shp(base).then(function(data){
        geo.addData(data);
        });

    var baseMaps = {
    "BaseLayer": watercolor
};
var overlays = {
        "shapefile": geo
    };
L.control.layers(baseMaps,overlays).addTo(m);




        </script>
```

It 's work, i can chose to display the shapefile or not.
But dont return all segmentation like here :http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#3/32.69/10.55

thank you